# Is function from topological group to metric space Borel?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, haar-measure, measure-theory

Let $G$ be a pseudometrizable compact abelian topological group, $X$ a compact
metric space and $f:X\rightarrow G$ a continuous bijective function.

Suppose there exists $g\in G$ such that if $d_{G}(g_{1},g_{2})\leq\epsilon$ then there exists
$n$ such that 
$d_{X}(f^{-1}g^{n}g_{1},f^{-1}g^{n}g_{2})\leq\epsilon.$

If $G$ is not metrizable then in general $f^{-1}$ is not continuous but can we conclude $f^{-1}$ is Borel?

Comment: Could you please add a few words of background and information? Otherwise it looks "too localized".

Comment: Sure. The multiplication of g is a dynamical system, a rotation in a compact abelian group. I want to construct a dynamical isomorphism from a dynamical system in X to G.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this.  I'm not using the hypothesis in your second paragraph, so maybe I am missing something.

Suppose $G$ is pseudometrizable but not metrizable.  The the closure of $\{e\}$, (the identity), is a closed subgroup $N$ of $G$.  And every open set in $G$ either contains $N$ or is disjoint from $N$.  Then this same thing is true for every Borel set.  On the other hand, for any  two points of $X$, there is an open set that contains one but not the other.  So, whatever bijection $f$ we choose, it is not Borel.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is something I don't understand.
Are you assuming the closure of the identity is not a single point? Is this is necessarily true?

Comment: Pseudo-metrizable but not metrizable means not Hausdorff, right?  In a topological group that is not Hausdorff, the closure of a single point is more than the point.  And the closure of a subgroup is a subgroup.